# Strange behaviour of selects with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using this code on the close function of a jQuery UI dialog:

```
close: function() {
                $('#type').append('<option value="99">'+ typename.val() +'</option>');
                $('#type option:last').attr("selected", true).siblings("option").removeAttr("selected");
                typename.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
```

The 99 is just a placeholder to see if works. Before closing this is how select looks like:

```
<select style="opacity: 0;" id="type" name="tipo">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Particular</option>
    <option value="2">Company</option>
    <option value="">Add new</option>
</select>
```

And after close:

```
<select style="opacity: 0;" id="type" name="tipo">
    <option value="1">Particular</option>
    <option value="2">Company</option>
    <option value="">Add new</option>
<option value="99">Test</option></select>
```

So, removes the selected but it doesn't add the selected. However if I try to alert $('#type').val() it shows 99. What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting the "after" code from Firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.6+, try this.

```
$('#type').prop('selectedIndex', $('#type option').length - 1);
```

OR

```
$("#type option[value='99']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

That is,

```
close: function() {
    $('#type').append('<option value="99">' + typename.val() + '</option>');
    $('#type').prop('selectedIndex', $('#type option').length - 1);
    typename.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
}
```

Comment: This does not change the selected option it remains <option value="1" selected="selected">Particular</option>. I've also used $('#type').val('99'); and doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#type option:last').attr("selected", "selected")
```

The value should be selected="selected", not true

Comment: Yeah, I just jsfiddled with it.  Both behave the same, but for me they both work.  http://jsfiddle.net/jNaEc/2/